# Holding down the left mouse button in AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I want a script where pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> makes AutoHotkey hold down the left mouse button. I then want the script to release the mouse once I press the key again.

How can I do that?

Comment: To those willing to close the thread: this is a programming question, AutoHotkey is a programming language.

Comment: @PhiLho: Thanks for pointing that out.  I nearly closed this myself.

Comment: @Pizza Overflow: You might want to consider including a short code snippet in AHK questions to avoid any confusion.  If you just include a short bit of code showing what you've tried so far, that should be enough that people won't mistakenly close your questions as "not programming related."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would use Click down and Click up

> [Click](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Click.htm) is generally preferred over [MouseClick](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseClick.htm) because it automatically compensates if the user has swapped the left and right mouse buttons via the system's control panel.

```
F1::
    alt := not alt
    if (alt)
    {
        Click down
    }
    else
    {
        Click up
    }
Return
```

Comment: I've needed to add `Return` at the end of the hotkey procedure code to make it work for me. `F1:: alt := not alt if(alt) { Click down } else { Click up } Return`

Answer (score 7):

Here is a one-liner in case anyone is interested:

```
F1::Click % GetKeyState("LButton") ? "Up" : "Down"
```

Comment: Can I use this one-liner for **Right Mouse Click**? Changing ``LButton`` -> ``RButton`` still appears to be trigger the Left Mouse Click....

Comment: Yes. `F1::Click right % GetKeyState("RButton") ? "Up" : "Down"` might do the job. If not do `F1::Click % "right " (GetKeyState("RButton") ? "Up" : "Down")`

Comment: Perfect! ``F1::Click % "right " (GetKeyState("RButton") ? "Up" : "Down")`` works as intended! Thanks Forivin!

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, I am a bit rusty in AHK programming, but here is what I tried, seems to work:

```
F1::
  alt := not alt
  If (alt)
  {
    MouseClick Left, 217, 51, , , D
  }
  Else
  {
    MouseClick Left, 217, 51, , , U
  }
Return
```

Comment: Using MouseClick is overkill and makes it look more complicated. Click Up/ Down should suffice.