# Autohotkey: Warning: This variable has not been assigned a value

Tags: autohotkey

People use [toggles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1993212/2841279) as simple as

```
alt := not alt
if(alt)  {...}
else     {...}
```

I implement it as

```
F1::
    alt := not alt
    if(alt)   ...
Return
```

When F1 is clicked, popup message shows:

> Warning: This variable has not been assigned a value.
>
> Specifically: atl (a global variable)
>
> --->  104: alt := not alt

I follow the example in [#warn](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/_Warn.htm), to add two lines before the `alt` line.  The same error still shows.

```
F1::
    #Warn
    ;alt := ""
    alt := not alt
    if(alt)
    {
    Click down
    }
    else
    {
    Click up
    }
Return
```

I have also tried to define alt outside of F1::, the same error still shows.

What should I do?  Is there any short fully working example using such toggles?

Answer (score 1):

This gives error

```
...
...
return

Alt := 0
F1::
    alt := not alt
    if(alt) { ..}
Return
```

This is ok

```
Alt := 0
F1::
    alt := not alt
    if(alt) { ..}
Return
```

`Alt := 0` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Warn is not always great, remove it unless you really need it

I did not test your code but it looks okay, is that is all of it?

```
Alt := 0

F1::
Alt := !Alt
;more
Return
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried:  1) Alt := 0 is needed   2) when a `return` before `F1::` { [exists](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/158da18d91bc9ee15830) }, the script can still detect F1, but gives the said error.  I commented the `return`, and everything is fine.